# Pause execution till Chrome is done loading

Tags: vba, excel, google-chrome, sendkeys

I'm currently in the process of developing a file which is used to fill in a form based on the data from the sheet. The issue I'm facing is that the page gets refreshed for each entered field for one section of the code. The refresh time varies based on the computer.

My current solution is to induce a wait of approximately 5-6 seconds which can be inefficient based on the terminal used. Is there a way that the execution can be paused simply till the page is done loading? Also, there are two versions of Excel that are in use, essentially 2013 and 2003. Not sure if that's relevant but I've had to sort out numerous compatibility issues.

Comment: Are you using sendkeys sent to a chrome browser?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SendKeys

Comment: That's my code, should it matter. I'm quite new to this so might not be the best formatting
https://gist.github.com/rxenox/832997e6c181be0f101acaa175ea0baf

Comment: This might help: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-firefox-or-chrome-with-vba-and-selenium/

Comment: I've come across that already, it appears to have compatibility issues with excel 2003 and I'm yet unable to see a function which can pause the code until the webpage has loaded :/